# JavaScript change div color with link

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementsbyname, parent-node

This seems really simple but Im brand new to JavaScript. I have a link on my page. When you click this link 2 things happen. 1) Using html the page jumps to the location of the referenced anchor tag on the page. 2) The div that holds the link changes its background color.

HTML

```
<a href="#abcd"  onclick="makeRed(this.href);">Link to div on page</a>

<div id="abcd">
    <a name="abcd">Not a clickable link.</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
function makeRed(x) {
var highlight=x.slice(-4);
document.getElementsByName(highlight).parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Firebug tells me document.getElementsByName(highlight).parentNode is undefined and this is where I'm confused.

Comment: Maybe try document.getElementByID("abcd")

Comment: Try document.getElementsByName( highlight )[ 0 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
document.getElementsByName(highlight).parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

with

`document.getElementsByName(highlight)[0].parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red";`

since getElementsByName returns an array

Comment: This also works. I give you the correct answer because using your method I dont have to add additional ids to my <a> tags.

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259)  returns a list (hence "...Elements...", rather than "...Element...").  Lists don't have parentNodes.

Either use `getElementById` to reference a single element with a given id, or iterate over the list returned by getElementsByName until you find the exact element you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I added an id to the <a> with no href and referenced with getElementById instead of getElementsByName and it worked.